# Elasticsearch proximity query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a query that can give me the following result

Find "A" & "B" which does not have "$$" in-between them

Eg

doc1: "A $$ B C D"

doc2: "B $$ A C D"

doc3: "A B $$ C D"

doc4: "A C D B $$"

the ans should be doc3 and doc4

Comment: Not sure if i understand - answer should be doc3 if you dont want $$ between A and B

Comment: my bad, yes the ans should be doc3, i am editing the question, thank ya

Comment: if i have some string with two chars such as ** , is that a valid answer - for example - is "A * B C D $$" valid response?

Comment: yes it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch analyzes the text and indexes in an inverted index. So it is key to know how your data is indexed to understand how to query it ( Data should be indexed the way you need to query ) .

Consider scenario where the above text is indexed with standard analyzer, which is default ( Elasticsearch provides _analyze API to test how your data is analyzed)

```
 curl http://localhost:9200/sampleindex/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=lowercase -d ' { "text" : "ab $$ cc", "analyzer": "standard" } ' 

 {"tokens":[{"token":"ab","start_offset":0,"end_offset":2,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"cc","start_offset":6,"end_offset":8,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}
```

Note that index got no knowledge of  token '$$' which means it is not possible to query it ( negative or positive).

If index mapping of the field contains proper analyzer , which will consider '$$' as a token then you can use a simple phrase query with in a must not .

Comment: oh okay, I get it.